# Pycharm GUI add file to .gitignore menu item disappears

Tags: git, pycharm

I started to use Pycharm with git and there is a strange behavior: when adding the first file to .gitignore everything is ok in the menu structure:

```
right-klick -> git -> add to .gitignore -> add to .gitignore    (1)
                                        -> .git/info/exclude    (2)
```

If a chose (1) the .gitignore is create and the file added.
BUT: after that, the menu structure is changed and 'add to .gitignore' has disappeared:

```
right-klick -> git -> .git/info/exclude
```

So I can not us the GUI to add further files/dirs to .gitignore.

Any Idea why that happens?
I also did not find a way to remove items from .gitignore other then modifying .gitignore directly.

btw the .gitignore plugin does not change anything.

Comment: Seems like a bug in pycharm. [Send a bug report](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/PY)